# Why CSS-Modules is affecting globally when working with html elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-modules

I have a file `mycomponent.module.css`

```
button {
    width: 10vw;
    min-width: 150px;
}
```

Unfortunately this css is affecting globally instead of the specific component where I am importing it. Does CSS modules not work on element names and only works on class-names? So `.button` instead of `button`?

Comment: Or are you looking for shadow-dom? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM

Comment: Can you share more details? Of course, the given styling applies to **all** `<button>` elements, as you haven't given any other criteria like an ID or class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Write like this.**

*Make a `Class` or `ID` and call them where is needed*.

```css
.bu{
    width: 10vw;
    min-width: 150px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<button class="bu">button1 </button><br><br>
<button>button2 ! </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to style a current button, you should give a className or Id to your button. In this case it was global, for all butons.